# How to update Python 2 data analysis code to Python 3?

Tags: string, split

I have inherited a data analysis script written in Python2, which I am trying to update so it runs on Spyder with Python3. When I run the script on Spyder (on MacOS), the following section:

```
  # Split filename info
                f_split1 = string.split(f,in_delim1) #first pass, splits by ' - '
                f_split2 = string.split(f_split1[0],in_delim2) #second pass, splits by '_'
                sID = f_split2[0]
```

gives me this error:

> AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'split'

I know from reading on Stack Overflow that the string bit is obsolete in Version 3, but I am not sure how to update the code and keep the (f,in_delim1) parts.

I'm pretty new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

Create own class or import string.

1. `class string: def split(self, a, b): #split logic`
2. `import string`